# I want to add string s5,s6,s7,s8 to sms android

Tags: android

i want to add string s5,s6,s7,s8 to sms but it accepts and display in message only upto s5 after action performed on android and sends only upto s5 how can i send  all strings via sms

```
                    String s = n.getText().toString();
                    String s1 = ci.getText().toString();
                    String s2 = cn.getText().toString();
                    String s3 = sr.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String s4 = mn.getText().toString();
                    String s5 = ml.getText().toString();
                    String s6 = spt.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String s7 = sui.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String s8 = d.getText().toString();


                    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    sms.sendTextMessage("phone number", null,
                                    "Name:" + s +
                                    "\nCollege id:" + s1 +
                                    "\nContact no:" + s2 +
                                    "\nYour Role:" + s3 +
                                    "\nMachine Number:" + s4 +
                                    "\nMachine Location:" + s5 +
                                    "\nMachine Location:" + s6 +
                                    "\nproblemDescription:" + s7 +
                                    "\nroleCombobox:" + s8
                            , sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

Comment: You're missing a `+` after s6 and s7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sendMultipartTextMessage, you need to break up the long message into an ArrayList of Strings. It then sends as many SMS as needed. In short:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(longMessage);
sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You know SMS length limit is 160 characters.

It's not a problem with string s5 after not displaying text. The actual problem is character limit so you can send sms in two part.

Comment: How ??  please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringbuilder` and check if the length of the string is 160 characters or greater if greater then as per the length divide the string into several halves.  ALso, using string builder is good choice in terms of `performance`.